# Noise removed but file duration reduced in SOX

Tags: sox

I use `sox` for Noise removal/reduction from audio but when I give these commands,

```
/usr/bin/sox input.wav -n noiseprof noise.prof  
/usr/bin/sox input.wav output.wav noisered noise.prof 0.2
```

`output.wav` duration in milliseconds is reduced.

My `input.wav` duration is 0.9 seconds, where `output.wav` is 0.772 seconds.
I also check on different lengths of audio but in every case, the file is reduced by 128 milliseconds.

So what's the reason behind this?

Is there any way we can just remove noise from audio without reducing the duration?